# getting null pointer exception in ServletContext

Tags: jsp, session, servlets, nullpointerexception

I am getting null pointer exception IDK. When I login into  webpage A ServletContect will set the Attribute

```
ServletContext context;
context=getServletContext();
context.setAttribute("userID", userID);
```

I initialize ServletContext in class level.
And I want to retrieve it  into others pages of jsp and servlets,

When I try to access the Attribute using
`context.getAttribute("userID");`
In other jsp and servlet I get Null pointer Exception,

I tried to use session to retrieve value using

```
session=request.getSession(false); 
session.getAttribute("userID");
```

but still get null pointer.

Comment: You initialize it to what?

Comment: ServletContext initialized in every servlet using get servletcontext () method.

Answer (score 0):

Use the HttpSession to Store userID.
It makes no sense of storing logged in user information in the ServletContext.

When user successfully authenticated create its session and store userID in session attribute Map.

```
HttpSession session= request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("userID", userID);
```

You can access userID in your JSP using EL:

```
${sessionScope.[userID]}
```

No matter whether you are using `Request Dispatcher` or `sendRedirect()` your session will remain valid until you:

1. Explicitly call `HttpSession.invalidate()` method on session object.
2. session timeout reached which you can declare in web.xml.

```xml
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Comment: I am not using request dispatched method, only response.sendRedirect() to go other pages,I will impact on that season's object.

Comment: When we pass TRUE as a parameter it will create a new session instead of joining created session as per my knowledge, I am still not getting your logic.plz explain. Thanks for answering.

Comment: you have to create a new session just after login, after that you have to get particular session by passing false in getSession() method. Go through Servlet and Jsp concepts.